# SQLite syntax error | check the presence of the table

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-studio

"EXISTS": syntax error (code 1):, while compiling: ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS CW_Elem ADD COLUMN Type TEXT;

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS " + groups + "_" + title + " ADD COLUMN " + str + " TEXT;");
```

How then to check the presence of the table and if it is to execute the request?
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syntax diagrams for SQLITE. Try [alter table](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Comment: How then to check the presence of the table and if it is to execute the request?

Comment: That's a different question. You asked about the syntax error. Perhaps an SQL expert can help.